# how to convert coordinates

Tags: matlab, math, scilab

I've got two segments that have the same lenght. I would like to find a way to convert the value of one to the other, I've tried a lot, but nothing solved the problem, any if that's possible.

here a MALTAB code for the two segments

```
clear 
clc 

x = linspace(24.27,29.77,100);
y = linspace(0.09,1.1,100);
```

Comment: Are you saying that `x=24.27` should be equal to `y=0.09` , `x=100 -> y=100` etc and then fit the values linearly? It is a bit unclear what you are asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to map the values this way?:

```
clear 
clc 


minX = 24.27;
maxX = 29.77;
minY = 0.09;
maxY = 1.1;
x = linspace(minX,maxX,100);
y = linspace(minY,maxY,100);

% from x to y
x_ = 24.27;

y_ = (x_-minX) / (maxX-minX) *(maxY-minY) +minY;
```

y_ = 0.09

Answer (score -1):

x = linspace(24.27,29.77,100);
y = linspace(0.09,1.1,100);

Maybe values in parenthesis ( x,y,z )
equals the hour, minute, second

google maps work this method too.

I did convert that format to lat,long ==>  **3951.7265,03328.7961** to 39.862108,33.479935

with this algorithm 
[Geographic coordinate conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion)